# Swift: Using switch statement in touchesBegan

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, switch-statement, skscene

I want to clean up my `touchesBegan(..)` in `SKScene`. I wanted to make a case statement instead of my `if .. else` chain.  However, I get errors when implementing, which suggests that I don't know how equality is done under the hood.

Before code:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if self.nodeAtPoint(location) === playLabel {
            buildLevelSelect()
        } else if self.nodeAtPoint(location) === aboutLabel {
            createAboutView()
        } else if self.nodeAtPoint(location) === storeLabel {
            createStore()
        }
    }
}
```

After code:  After clicking around, some label clicks work, but some others raise a `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode 0x0)` error:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        switch(self.nodeAtPoint(location)){
        case playLabel :
            buildLevelSelect()
        case aboutLabel :
            createAboutView()
        case storeLabel :
            createStore()
        default : break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this would be by populating the `.name` property of your nodes, so then you could switch on the name instead.  So then your switch would look like this:

```
switch (self.nodeAtPoint(location).name ?? "") { 
    case "playLabel" :
        buildLevelSelect()
    case "aboutLabel" :
        ...
```

Comment: **This is the best way to do it.** @cdpalmer You should check if a string is equal to another string (name), not compare two object that could be different also if you use the binary operator === (for example two string with the same return a crash if one is String and the other is NSString) ...

Comment: This makes sense.  I would have to do some refactoring, I only figured out you could tie string names to objects halfway through my side project.

Answer (score 5):

You can write a sort of odd looking but functional `switch` if you want the `===` behavior as follows:

```
switch(true){
        case self.nodeAtPoint(location) === playLabel : buildLevelSelect()
        case self.nodeAtPoint(location) === aboutLabel : createAboutView()
        case self.nodeAtPoint(location) === storeLabel : createStore()
        default : break
}
```

In my opinion, this is still cleaner looking than the if-else chain.

Comment: Ohh... thinking outside the box.  I like this.  I'll wait a day or two to feel out others before accepting an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can also cast the objects in the switch statement and then your code works as expected

```
    if let touch = touches.first as UITouch! {

        let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)

        switch self.atPoint(touchLocation) {
            case redBox as SKSpriteNode:
                print("touched redBox")
            case greenBox as SKSpriteNode:
                print("touched greenBox")
            default:
                print("touched nothing")
        }
    }
```